# how to delete a file from AWS S3 bucket using AWS-SDK by a user

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was uploading the files to S3 bucket from my application to a particular folder.
Now I need an option for the user to delete the file so that it should Delete in the bucket.

I have searched many blogs but couldn't find a proper solution through Frontend Angular Application.

Hoping the best solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: One way is to create a lambda function that exposes by API get way- gets the file name as input and delete it.

Comment: @AmitBaranes ,Thanks for your reply. Cant, we do it straight from the frontend, just like I upload the video.